# C: memcpy segfault with void* pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, memcpy

Code -- Main loop:

```
int handleClient (struct clientData* clientData)
{
    void* Buffer = malloc (INET_BUFFER_SIZE); <-- VOID* BUFFER FOR RECV()
    int listenSocket = clientData->listenSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress = clientData->clientAddress;

    printf("Received connection from client %s:%d.\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddress.sin_port));

while (1)
{
    int packetSize;
    if ((packetSize = recv(listenSocket, &Buffer, INET_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0)
    {
        if (packetSize == ECHO_SIZE)
        {
            handleEchoPacket(Buffer);
            continue;
        }

        if (packetSize == MESSAGE_SIZE) <---THIS IS TRIGGERED BECAUSE OF PACKET SIZE
        {
            handleMessagePacket(Buffer);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Code -- handleMessagePacket(void* Buffer):

```
void handleMessagePacket (void* Buffer)
{

    void* localBuffer = (void*) malloc(INET_BUFFER_SIZE);
    memcpy(localBuffer, Buffer, INET_BUFFER_SIZE); <--SEGFAULT
    (...)
}
```

GDB -- Partial output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memcpy_sse2_unaligned () (.....) <--Tells me it doesn't have source files, not relevant to the problem.
```

Basically, the problem happens when I copy one memory block from a void pointer to a local buffer. Both were malloc() heap memory of same type: void.
Any suggestions or comments are welcome!

Comment: You need to use `recv(listenSocket, Buffer, INET_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);` -- without the `&` before `Buffer`.

Comment: I literally realized this 10 seconds ago. This kept me up a while. Baby steps. Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is happening: when you pass the address of `Buffer` to `recv`, received data is placed in the space allocated to the address of your buffer, which is on the stack. When you subsequently call `handleMessagePacket`, the address that you pass is no longer valid: it has been written over by `recv`!

Removing the ampersand from the call of `recv` should fix this problem:

```
if ((packetSize = recv(listenSocket, Buffer, INET_BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0)
//                                  ^^ No ampersand
```

In general, situations like this are best diagnosed with a memory profiler, such as valgrind. The tool would promptly tell you that there is an invalid write into stack area for the `Buffer` write, and that the subsequent dereference of received data as a pointer (the issue that causes SIGSEGV now) is an invalid read.